# Is it possible to instantiate a generic type's property through reflection?

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, reflection

I am trying to create an abstract class that initializes `T` class properties by iterating a json-style object passed in constructor.

```
 abstract class JSONClass<T> {
  // Receive a JSON object implementing all T properties
  constructor(json: JSONClassDictionary<T>) {
    this.fromJSON(json);
  }


  fromJSON(json: JSONClassDictionary<T>) {
    for (let key in json){
      let prop = this[key];
      if (prop is not a class) {  <// -- 1) Determine whether it's a class
        this[key] = prop;
      }
      else{
        const constructor = getConstructorOf(T[key]) // <-- 2) Get constructor of T[Key] property. This is no-sense to compiler
        this[key] = new constructor(prop)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `T` may have some properties which are not primitive types, and require initialization.

Example of **real case scenario** and invocation:

```
class UserRole extends JSONClass<UserRole> {
  id;
  name;
  permissionGroup: PermissionGroup;

}

const role = UserRole({
  id: 1,
  name: "Admin",
  permissionGroup: {// <-- This will be converted to PermissionGroup() in fromJSON
    id: 1,
    action: ".."  
  }
})
```

This means that when `fromJSON` is iterating through the property `permissionGroup`, it should *not* perform `this[key] = prop;` but `this[key] = new PermissionGroup(prop)`.

I am having issues in **Point (1)** and **Point (2)** as shown in code comments, specifically in:

1. Being able to determine whether the key I'm iterating in `json` is an **instantiable class** property of `T`, instead of a primitive type;
2. If true, the initialize property of `T`.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example

Comment: TypeScript’s static type system is erased upon transpilation to JavaScript; there’s no native “reflection” to speak of.  If you want this information you’ll have to provide it at runtime, say, via a configuration object that names or supplies the appropriate constructor as the value of the relevant property key.

Comment: What do you think of an approach like [this](//tsplay.dev/w14p2W) where you give a config/schema object and the proper deserializing class constructor is generated (and additionally a reserializing `toJSON()` method is included)?  Note that you are inferring types from the schema object and not the other way around (which would not be possible since types are not present at runtime).  If this works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please describe the unsatisfied use cases in your [mre] (and you should give types for `PermissionGroup`, etc and not leave anything as pseudocode).

Comment: @jcalz I must really say that I am impressed by the solution you came with. It is definitely something that solves my issue completely, and moreover you're on spot with the `toJSON()`! Please write an answer as soon as you can. I appreciate the effort you put into clarifying and providing me with a solution to this

Comment: @jcalz I have tried your example with an `enum` but it does not work. What am I missing? Check this [Playground](https://pastebin.com/yMDQFqUH). I get "enum not assignable to type of Maker<>"

Comment: @jcalz Other few catches: similar error is being thrown when I attempt to use a `type` value. Moreover it seems I cannot declare array of primitive types like `J.Array(string)` or even `string[]`. Throws: `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value`

Comment: your pastebin says "This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff." so you might want to fix that.  I think [this code](//tsplay.dev/NaYr2N) will work for an array of primitives, but you need to use `J.Array(J.string)`.  You can't write `string` or `string[]` there because there is no value with those names (and `string[]` isn't even a valid value name); do you understand [type erasure](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure)  There is nothing named `string` or `string[]` at runtime.

Comment: BTW I think [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WzLPeN) might be an improvement in JSON serialization since you want to catch mutated properties I assume.  Anyway, make sure the code here works for your use cases and edit your question with code that shows problems (editing the question is preferable to comments, since they are apparently things you need to work, and anyone answering would need to meet those needs)